# No such file or directory error when deploying .war file to Google App Engine Flexible Environment

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, plantuml

I'm trying to deploy [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/plantuml/files/plantuml.war/download) PlantUML Server .war file to GAE. I've followed Google's instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/deploy-flex-jar), but am getting the following error from Eclipse:

```
    (gcloud.app.deploy) Cloud build failed. Check logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/builds/39606ad7-fedf-4418-8944-4cadefccaedf?project=practice-area Failure status: UNKNOWN: Error Response: [2] Build failed; check build logs for details
```

When I check the logs at the link, I get this:

```
starting build "39606ad7-fedf-4418-8944-4cadefccaedf"

FETCHSOURCE
Fetching storage object: gs://staging.practice-area.appspot.com/us.gcr.io/practice-area/appengine/default.20180320t172224:latest#1521559359013330
Copying gs://staging.practice-area.appspot.com/us.gcr.io/practice-area/appengine/default.20180320t172224:latest#1521559359013330...
/ [0 files][ 0.0 B/ 8.0 MiB] 
/ [1 files][ 8.0 MiB/ 8.0 MiB] 
-
Operation completed over 1 objects/8.0 MiB. 
BUILD
Starting Step #0
Step #0: Pulling image: gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/java/runtime-builder@sha256:abe30c228acd8514d83430452b5a45eedea568b55d02d4ddaa2a374b1b086dd8
Step #0: sha256:abe30c228acd8514d83430452b5a45eedea568b55d02d4ddaa2a374b1b086dd8: Pulling from gcp-runtimes/java/runtime-builder
Step #0: Digest: sha256:abe30c228acd8514d83430452b5a45eedea568b55d02d4ddaa2a374b1b086dd8
Step #0: Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/java/runtime-builder@sha256:abe30c228acd8514d83430452b5a45eedea568b55d02d4ddaa2a374b1b086dd8
Step #0: INFO - Identified Java artifact for deployment Artifact{type=WAR, path=/workspace/plantuml (1).war}
Step #0: INFO - Using base image 'gcr.io/google-appengine/jetty@sha256:dcfc5cf6401fc2ed99df12da8ee54f22e0e8e95247a239845ca4c513c0f42e11' for WAR artifact
Step #0: INFO - Generating Dockerfile at /workspace/Dockerfile
Step #0: INFO - Generating .dockerignore file at /workspace/.dockerignore
Finished Step #0
Starting Step #1
Step #1: Pulling image: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:e07e5c3acceaae1fe5f0d8eaf9718c7f53ffd35f8a7d6b2491af5a0838242261
Step #1: sha256:e07e5c3acceaae1fe5f0d8eaf9718c7f53ffd35f8a7d6b2491af5a0838242261: Pulling from cloud-builders/docker
Step #1: cf2c5e27174e: Already exists
Step #1: a7bc5eb395b5: Already exists
Step #1: a19c45128315: Already exists
Step #1: 23909d8a304f: Pulling fs layer
Step #1: 23909d8a304f: Verifying Checksum
Step #1: 23909d8a304f: Download complete
Step #1: 23909d8a304f: Pull complete
Step #1: Digest: sha256:e07e5c3acceaae1fe5f0d8eaf9718c7f53ffd35f8a7d6b2491af5a0838242261
Step #1: Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:e07e5c3acceaae1fe5f0d8eaf9718c7f53ffd35f8a7d6b2491af5a0838242261
Step #1: Sending build context to Docker daemon 9.062MB

Step #1: Step 1/2 : FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/jetty@sha256:dcfc5cf6401fc2ed99df12da8ee54f22e0e8e95247a239845ca4c513c0f42e11
Step #1: sha256:dcfc5cf6401fc2ed99df12da8ee54f22e0e8e95247a239845ca4c513c0f42e11: Pulling from google-appengine/jetty
Step #1: Digest: sha256:dcfc5cf6401fc2ed99df12da8ee54f22e0e8e95247a239845ca4c513c0f42e11
Step #1: Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/google-appengine/jetty@sha256:dcfc5cf6401fc2ed99df12da8ee54f22e0e8e95247a239845ca4c513c0f42e11
Step #1: ---> 6d61d7057b61
Step #1: Step 2/2 : COPY ./plantuml (1).war $APP_DESTINATION
Step #1: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder056091656/plantuml: no such file or directory
Finished Step #1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:e07e5c3acceaae1fe5f0d8eaf9718c7f53ffd35f8a7d6b2491af5a0838242261" failed: exit status 1
```

I can't figure out how to troubleshoot this. The error seems to be "no such file or directory", however I can't figure out why that would be, shouldn't the deployment process create all necessary directories?

Any input is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: use markdown formatting to improve your post make it more legible.

Comment: I could deploy it without problem. Can you specify the options you have chosen for the check-boxes (step 8 and 9 of the guide)?

Comment: All 3 boxes are checked. Promote... Stop... and Include...
I just created a fresh project and am getting the same error:

Step #1: Step 2/2 : COPY ./plantuml (1).war $APP_DESTINATION
Step #1: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder056091656/plantuml: no such file or directory

Comment: Can you try to change your WAR name from `plantuml (1).war` to `plantuml(1).war`. Deleting the space in the filename will make it work.

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the space from your filename. Try to not use spaces in filenames because they might be misinterpreted as different parameters.

Change your WAR name from plantuml (1).war to plantuml(1).war will make it work.